# How to refresh video view every 10 seconds in android?

Tags: android, self-updating

I want to update a view every 10 seconds, but how would I go about that?

How would I go about that? I've seen some samples use "Run()" and "Update()", but that doesn't seem to help when I try it, any ideas?

Right now I have:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      Vitamio.isInitialized(this);
        Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext());
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);
        Log.d("url=", getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        init();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update a `View` every 10s, you must call a thread. Add following code in your onCreate() method:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        Thread.sleep(10000); // every 10s
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // update View here!
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: Worked , Great Thanks :)

Comment: Happy coding @Dr.Mezo

Comment: Do you have an idea . if i want to link the time "10000"
to web page so i can control the refresh time from outside the app ?

Comment: No idea about that but worth trying.

Comment: if i have something like http://example.com/time.php  and the output is just 20000

so how can i link this to control time of refresh

Comment: @WilliamSeemann I tried with thread because it was easy and workes in background. Im kinda noob here